# Problem with transferring/receiving an Excel file from the backend(django_v1.9.11) to the frontend(angularjs)

Tags: django, angularjs

On the front end there is a table and a button to export to Excel. When you click on it, you need to send ajax to the backend, generate an Excel file and transfer it to the frontend in order to download it through the browser to disk.

## Backend (django v1.9.11)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from django.http import HttpResponse


def send_xl(self, request):
      
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    
    # this is test data. real data is hidden
    sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
    sheet['B1'] = 'Excel with Django.'

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_excel_file.xlsx'
    wb.save(response)

    return response
```

## HTML element

```
<button ng-click="downloadExcel()">
    Export
</button>
```

## Frontend (angularjs)

```
$scope.downloadExcel = function(){
    $.get("", {action:"send_xl", col: $scope.col, sortDirection: $scope.sortDirection }).
    then(function (response){
    let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'filename.xlsx';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

I expect that when the button is clicked, the browser will download a file that can be opened through Excel. The file is downloading, but Excel gives an error:

(I open it via LibreOffice)
"The file 'filename.xlsx' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file.

The corruption could be the result of document manipulation or of structural document damage due to data transmission.

We recommend that you do not trust the content of the repaired document.
Execution of macros is disabled for this document.

Should LibreOffice repair the file?"

Tell me what I'm doing wrong. What don't I understand?
Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Did you try to open that file in Microsoft Excel? There are cases, when Excel opens an .xslx file quite well, but LibreOffice doesn't.